# Qt5 WebFrame offscreen rendering

Tags: c++, html, qt, rendering

I need to create web page thumbnails **offscreen**.
In fact i need to create a **command line tool** that will be called from ssh sessions and run in virtual machines **without display/screens**.

I use [this code](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qwebpage.html), customize it by using only a webPage:

```
QWebPage myWebPage.
myWebPage.setViewportSize(QSize(320,240));
myWebPage.mainFrame()->load(QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com"));
QImage myRenderedFrame( QSize(320,240), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
QPainter painter(&myRenderedFrame);
myWebPage.mainFrame()->render(&painter);
painter.end();
myRenderedFrame.save("/a/path.png");
```

My application needs to link with QtGui / QtWebKitWidgets / QtWidgets. I think that without those libs, i could launch it without display.

I also tried to pass *-platform=offscreen* but it doesn't work.

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Abandon (core dumped)
```

Comment: Consider trying something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/).

Comment: @elmigranto : Thank you, great idea. But, even if Phantom uses Qt, the CSS3 rendering (with PhantomJS at least) is really better with QtWebKit (in Qt5.1), specially rotated CSS text